# Setting up a Drupal environment on Ubuntu

Tags: installation

After a few years of setting basic Drupal environments on Windows only, with WAMP (both the installment and the WAMP program) and Drush 7.0.0, I came to the conclusion I also need to work with LAMP and especially Ubuntu-based as it would give me access to more development tools, and more easily, for example in relation to tar, tar.gz, curl (non-core UNIX command), Composer, Drush master (which as of 2015 is not recommended for Windows usage) Xdebug, and more.

I have installed Ubuntu on a virtual machine, but what do I do now? Of course there is no WAMP (Windows, AMP) on Linux, and my options seem to be manual installation of the server \ Linux-XAMPP... But besides that, my question is what are the main differences between a Windows Drupal environment to a Linux one, in these points:

- Is there something else needed for a Drupal (8) environment besides the things I mentioned?
- In Windows, my WAMP folder was in c:\WAMP\ --- What is the drupal folder hierarchy in Linux?

Please answer on these points and detail as much as you can on the process, for newcomers like me could have a nicer acquaintance.

Comment: check this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Drupal

Comment: in ubuntu it's called LAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Ubuntu doesn't come with LAMP out of the box but it's super easy to set up with `sudo apt-get` ubuntu command. The basics of setting up a lamp environment are beyond the scope on an answer here, but there are plenty of tutorials on how to do it and robust community of Ubuntu users for questions.

Based on what you're describing, I would recommend using ubuntu desktop rather than server on your VM. This will give you a GUI interface which will be a little more familiar than trying to run Unix commands through your terminal on the VM, which will require further setup of your windows box.

Once you've set your VM up the basics you will need are: Mysql (or your db of choice), php, and Apache (or your web server of choice). You can download and install all of these free, but you'll do most of this from the command I mentioned above, so I would school up if you're not comfortable [Ubuntu LAMP set up](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu). There are many tutorials on how to turn Ubuntu into a wed dev machine, pick and choose what you find useful.

You'll have to set up the Mysql server and most of the programs manually before you have a set up you can install drupal on.

To answer your two questions:

1. No, you don't need any tools that you didn't mention, although depending on your set up and being new to Unix environments I would look into GUI tools like Mysql workbench.
2. Ubuntu Desktop and Server have a designated html folder it will be in 
    /var/www/html

Where it gets tricky for someone who isn't familiar with the environment is that you need to configure your folder and file permissions  for the /var/www/html folder. It has to be owned and readable to the apache or your webserver user.

This here is a good tutorial, it will get you where you need to go once you have a working LAMP server on your dev machine.[Ubuntu Drupal](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-drupal-on-ubuntu-14.04)

So, from here you have to ssh into your virtual machine or use the GUI interface to set your drupal install. This is the same as on windows:

1. Get a copy of Drupal Core in your web root folder.
2. create a drupal database, database user
3. point your site to the db with settings.php in your sites folder.
4. Run the install.php script in your web browser.
5. drupal and profit.

You mentioned using a lot of Drupal dev tools. You'll have to configure those yourself, but you'll have to either do it on the VM (and work natively on VM) or configure your windows drush to connect to your VM like you would a remote server. This is all good practice but, beyond the scope of a single post.

Comment: Thanks for the detailing! What about the folders: /$ > etc > php5\phpmyadmin\mysql && /$ > usr > share > apache2 ? I've seen a guide that mentions them...

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head about those folders. They are system and program folders for ubuntu and phpmyadmin. To install Phymyadmin I think you can just install with apt-get. The basics of installing drupal are in my answer above, you can google setting up a dev environment to your liking.

Comment: The basics of installing it on Ubuntu I guess you meant... Anyway, I asked about these folders just to know if you ever needed to deal with them... I now understand that you did not...

Comment: In all humbleness, it's not a lot for me - Again, till now I installed all via UI with the program WAMP, under Windows. I haven't checked the guides yet; It was important for me to first hear from you about these two folders I read about in another guide. If you haven't worked with them it but strengtheners what another developer told me --- The other guide I read over complicates things. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I made a similar "jump" to a LAMP environment (to start working on D7). At the time I got a recommendation to "start" with the [Quickstart: Prebuilt Drupal Development Environment](https://www.drupal.org/project/quickstart) project.

This project today is "unsupported", though it may (still) be worth checking out to get an idea about the various components/features it included (Drush, etc).

The project page also suggests these possible alternatives:

> - [DrupalPro 14](https://github.com/jcmartinez/drupalpro14).
> - [Lazy Dubuntu](http://lazydubuntu.com/) - A shell script that will set-up your Drupal Dev Environment in Ubuntu.
> - [DrupalPro](http://drupal.org/project/drupalpro) - Unity-based fork of Quickstart 1.
> - [BitNami Drupal Stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/drupal) - All-in-one free native installers, virtual machines, and Cloud Images that simplify the Drupal installation and hosting.